# Where can I find the Vedas to read?

Tags: vedas

I was searching over the Internet for a long time to find and read the Vedas but it didn't help. Few persons have mentioned that the Vedas will not be in a readable format. Is there any source where I can read the Vedas online or offline?

Comment: may be it help to you http://vedpuran.net/download-all-ved-and-puran-pdf-hindi-free/

Comment: To understand Vedas comprehensively and precisely in this life alone, you **MUST** go to **GURU**.

Comment: Anil Kumar, provide an authoritative source for your statement. Better one from non-sectarian sources.

Comment: It is said that to understand the vedas you need to read with the commentators, to read without the commentators is foolish. Find your teacher first. Your teacher will know when it is time to read the vedas - and in what order. Everyone is different...This is told over and over in the Upanishads. See GIta 4.34

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Well from what I know by reading different autobiographies of great yogis, it is guru who finds disciple and not the other way round.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria In a sense, yes. But you have to make the initial effort. It is said that for every step you make towards the Lord, He makes 10 steps towards you.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria See also Uddhava Gita VI. 48, VII 1-9, XXI. 26, 28-35 for Krishna's teachings on it.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Krishna says in Uddhava Gita II. 19.: "Very often in the world men who have truly discerned the truth about the universe deliver themselves from evil inclinations through their own exertions." Ramakrishna Paramahamsa says: 'A mother ignores a child so long as it is busy with its toys. But as soon as the child puts down the toys and cries for its mother, the mother comes running.' If you can cry with tears for God, your Guru will find you. If you cannot, then go looking with your own self exertion.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda very well said!

Comment: Do you want to know about vedas or vedas?