# English Transliteration of Vedas and Upanishads

Tags: vedas, upanishads

Translations of the Vedas and Upanishads are available in great numbers online, but unfortunately, the transliteration of Vedas is rare to find.

Thus, I would like to know where can I find the **transliteration** of the Vedas and Upanishads **into English**, **online**, and **free**?

Note that this question is **NOT AT ALL A DUPLICATE OF EITHER OF THE FOLLOWING**:

[Where can I find the authentic and complete Vedas online? [Hindi + English]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8304/15963)

[Online version of Vedas, Puranas, Sutras, and Shastras in Devanagari/Sanskrit](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29667/15963)

[What are some online sources to get unabridged Hindu Scriptures or to learn Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15424/15963)

[Where can I find the Vedas to read?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9757/15963)

[Where can I get authentic translation of all four Vedas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19471/15963)

[How did the Vedas in Hinduism come into existence?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/774/15963)

Each of the above asks for online **translations**, or transliterations in Devanagari or Hindi, but kindly note, that I am asking for the  online **transliterations** of the four Vedas, along with their principal Upanishads, into English.

Also note that I would like a complete transliteration of the Vedas, and not transliterations of individual portions or Suktas of the Vedas.

Comment: English transliteration? If yes, add it to the title.

Comment: You can find English transliteration of Rig Veda in sacred-texts.com and also in aurobindo.ru

Comment: For Upanishads you may go to wisdomlib.org

Comment: @Spark You may want to post an answer instead.

Comment: There are many online transliteration tools which do the same work. If you have those, you can transliterate any number of books. But what important in Vedas and Upanishads is swara. They are not followed in transliteration.

Comment: On [Sanskrit Documents](https://sanskritdocuments.org/), you'll always find ITRANS at itx link to *every available text*; e.g. [this one](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/shveta.itx) for Shvetashvatara Upanishad for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [GRETIL](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil.htm) website has Sanskrit-to-English transliteration of most Hindu scriptures.

- Vedas are available [here](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil.htm#Veda)
- For Upaniṣads, check [this](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil.htm#Upan) link

[TITUS](http://titus.uni-frankfurt.de/indexe.htm?/texte/texte.htm), [Digital Corpus of Sanskrit](http://www.sanskrit-linguistics.org/dcs/index.php?contents=texte) and [Wisdom Library](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism) are few other places where you can find the transliterated Hindu texts.

IIT Kanpur's [Upanishads](https://www.upanishads.iitk.ac.in) website also hosts transliterations of the principal upaniṣads in various Indian languages including English.

Comment: For the Samaveda, the website only has Ārcikas, and no Gānas. Could you please provide a link where the Gānas are also available?

Comment: Do you want to chant the mantras using English transliteration? I doubt if it's possible. Google "archive.org Sama Veda Samhita Satyaprakash Saraswati" and see if it has what you need.

Comment: Nope... This book too has only the Ārcikas. No Gānas.. :(

Comment: See what R L Kashyap says about the Sāmagāna mantras on Introduction [pg 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NlsD.jpg) & [pg 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux96v.jpg). So looks like even the Sanskrit version of Sāmagāna is not easily available and here you are searching for English transliteration of the same :)

Comment: Oh ok... did not know that...

Answer (score 0):

Causelessmercy.com is an excellent source of original Gudiya Vaishnava scriptures. You will find original Bhagavad-Gita, complete Srimad-Bhagavatam and other books by Srila Prabhupada, who was an enlightened master. They all have original Sanskrit verses with transliterations, translations and purports. Here's an example:

> *sri-bhagavan uvaca
>
>   kutas tva kasmalam idam
>
>   visame samupasthitam
>
>   anarya-justam asvargyam
>
>   akirti-karam arjuna*
>
> SYNONYMS
>
> *sri bhagavan uvaca*—the Supreme Personality of Godhead said;
>   *kutah*—wherefrom; *tva*—unto you; *kasmalam—dirtiness;* *idam*—this
>   lamentation; *visame*—this hour of crisis; *samupasthitam*—arrived;
>   *anarya*—persons who do not know the value of life; *justam*—practiced by;
>   *asvargyam*—that which does not lead to higher planets; *akirti*—infamy;
>   *karam*—the cause of; *arjuna*—O Arjuna.
>
> TRANSLATION
>
> The Supreme Person [Bhagavan] said: My dear Arjuna, how have these
>   impurities come upon you? They are not at all befitting a man who
>   knows the progressive values of life. They do not lead to higher
>   planets, but to infamy.

As you can see the book is authoritative.

Other good source of original Vedic scriptures is sacred-texts.com. There in the Hinduism section you will find original Vedas, Mahabharata, Ramayana and others.

Comment: Which transliteration scheme is this following?

Comment: These websites are really good, but I’m specifically looking for websites that have transliterations of the Vedas and Upanishads. Your answer mentions the Gita, Bhagavatam, Ramayana and Mahabharata. Also, sacred-texts has the transliteration of only the Rig Veda.

Comment: Try interntarchive. There you may find other books.